# How to use create threadpool/executor service in JBoss EAP 5.1

Tags: threadpool, jboss5.x, executor

i need to create threads to call asynchronously several other webservices inside my own webservice.
how can i safely configure thread pools inside Jboss EAP 5.1.

i have tried deploying below XML config to jboss

```
    <deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0">
        <bean name="CustomWorkManagerThreadPool" class="org.jboss.util.threadpool.BasicThreadPool">
             <annotation>@org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.aspects.jmx.JMX(name="custom:service=CustomWorkManagerThreadPool", exposedInterface=org.jboss.util.threadpool.BasicThreadPoolMBean.class)</annotation>
             <property name="name">CustomWorkManager</property>
             <property name="maximumQueueSize">100</property>
             <property name="maximumPoolSize">10</property>
             <property name="keepAliveTime">60000</property>
         </bean>

         <bean name="CustomWorkManager" class="org.jboss.resource.work.JBossWorkManager">
             <annotation>@org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.aspects.jmx.JMX(name="sdr:service=CustomWorkManager", exposedInterface=org.jboss.resource.work.JBossWorkManagerMBean.class)</annotation>
             <property name="threadPool"><inject bean="CustomWorkManagerThreadPool"/></property>
             <property name="XATerminator"><inject bean="TransactionManager" property="XATerminator"/></property>
         </bean>
   </deployment>
```

but got below error when running code:
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: custom:service=CustomWorkManager is not registered.

this is how i try to use it in my code:
...

WorkManager manager = (WorkManager) server.getAttribute(new ObjectName("custom:service=CustomWorkManager"), "Instance");

Work aWork1 = new TestWorkObject(1);
wm.startWork(aWork1);

...

i don't have any compile time error.

Comment: Can you add in what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

this one is working. i just had the wrong name in my code.
should be sdr:service=CustomWorkManager